# Downgrade Drush from 8-dev to 7

Tags: drush

I installed Drush  with `composer global require drush/drush:dev-master` but it has some problems. I am using Xampp and Windows 8.

How can I downgrade Drush from 8-dev to 7?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first uninstall (remove) the version you don't want anymore (8-dev) and then try install the version you want.

So, first run  `drush status`; then look for `drush script`. You can see the directory Drush was installed on your computer; try remove it manually or with `rmdir <path>`.

And according to [Drush Documentation page](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/), install the version you want (i.e. 7).

```
  composer global require drush/drush:7.*
```

Answer (score 5):

```
# Remove the current version of drush.
composer global remove drush/drush
# Install drush version 7.
composer global require drush/drush:7.*
```

Comment: It might help to explain what those lines of code do the person asking understands the impact of running those commands.

Comment: It seemed obvious to me, but, ok.

Comment: 'global' means that composer will use your /home directory, for your user. Not your current directory, for your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can install drush as [git clone](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush), and either checkout master or a tag to accomplish this.  Just remember to do a `composer install` if you checkout a version that uses composer (pretty sure all of the 7.x tags do, not sure about the 6.x tags), or add this as a post-checkout hook.